# Looking for an iterative loop in python which can add up all column values if certain condition meets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns m, n:

```
m=[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
n=[6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5, 1]
```

I am looking for an iterative loop that adds up values of column n if the value in column m is non-zero. For example at 3rd place of column m the value is 1 (non-zero) so it should add in the column n from index 0 to 2 i.e. 6+1+2=9. Similarly, at m[6]=4 (non-zero) this implies 1+4+3+1=9 and so on.

Comment: shouldn't the value at index 6 be 10? It would be better to provide the full output

Comment: I edited please check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a dataframe and you want to sum the elements in each column based on the position of non-zero values in column "m". The following code gives you the output as a dataframe. See the comment in the code if you are just looking for summing the values in column "n":

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

m = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
n = [1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
r = [randint(1, 3) for _ in m]
names = ['lev', 'yan', 'coke' , 'coke', 'yan', 'lev', 'lev', 'yan', 'lev']
df = pd.DataFrame({'m': m, 'n': n, 'r': r, 'names': names})
print(f"Input dataframe:\n{df}")

# if you want to iterate over all columns
iter_cols = df.columns.tolist()
iter_cols.remove('m')
# To iterate over an specific column (e.g. 'n') you use iter_cols = ['n']

starting_idx = 0
sum_df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, val in enumerate(df.m):
    if val != 0:
        sum_df = sum_df.append(df.iloc[starting_idx: (idx+1)][iter_cols].sum(), ignore_index=True)
        starting_idx = idx+1
print(f"Output dataframe:\n{sum_df}")
```

Output:

```
Input dataframe:
   m  n  r names
0  0  1  2   lev
1  1  1  3   yan
2  0  3  1  coke
3  0  4  2  coke
4  1  1  2   yan
5  0  1  3   lev
6  0  2  3   lev
7  0  1  3   yan
8  2  3  2   lev
Output dataframe:
     n         names     r
0  2.0        levyan   5.0
1  8.0   cokecokeyan   5.0
2  7.0  levlevyanlev  11.0
```

And if you want to iterate over distinct values in names column and sum the values in 'n' column accordingly:

```
iter_cols = ['n']
distinct_names = set(df.names)
print(distinct_names)
out_dct = {}
for name in distinct_names:
    starting_idx = 0
    sum_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for idx, val in enumerate(df.names):
        if val == name:
            sum_df = sum_df.append(df.iloc[starting_idx: (idx+1)][iter_cols].sum(), ignore_index=True)
            starting_idx = idx+1
    out_dct[name] = sum_df
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Erfun it worked but actually, I am looking to extend it to the dataframe which has 3rd column with different names. let me know how to extend so that the loop iterates through each name and does the above iteration.
m=[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
names=[lev, yan, coke , coke, yan, lev, lev, yan, lev, yan, lev, yan, coke, coke, coke, lev, yan, lev, lev, yan, coke]
n=[1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: Do you want to do the same for all other columns as well? or just column "n"?

Comment: Just add up column n values (just like you did already) only for each distinct value of column name. Like for coke it should do the same separately, similarly for lev and so on.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide an output for your example?

Comment: Thanks, it almost does the trick just let me know how to append 0 to the r column you added when m=0.

Comment: m=[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1]
n=[6, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5, 10]
starting_idx = 0
sum_lst = []
for idx, val in enumerate(m):
    if val != 0:
        sum_lst.append(sum(n[starting_idx: (idx+1)]))
        starting_idx = idx+1
print(sum_lst)
This was working well but need to look up distinct values of the names column. The code you updated is just assigning random integers between 1 and 3 which is not required it. @Erfun.